# Types of wsdl in salesforce

Tags: soap, wsdl

I am new to salesforce soap api, I found there are multiple types of wsdl in salesforce.

What is the difference between enterprise and partner wsdl and how to choose which wsdl type we should select for our requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce provide 2 types of WSDL. They are Enterprise and Partner.

**Enterprise WSDL**

1. The Enterprise WSDL is strongly typed.
2. The Enterprise WSDL is tied (bound) to a specific configuration of Salesforce (ie. a specific organization's Salesforce configuration).
3. The Enterprise WSDL changes if modifications (e.g custom fields or custom objects) are made to an organization's Salesforce configuration.

For the reasons outlined above, the Enterprise WSDL is intended primarily for Customers.

**Partner WSDL**

1. The Partner WSDL is loosely typed.
2. The Partner WSDL can be used to reflect against/interrogate any configuration of Salesforce (ie. any organization's Salesforce configuration).
3. The Partner WSDL is static, and hence does not change if modifications are made to an organization's Salesforce configuration.

For the reasons outlined above, the Partner WSDL is intended primarily for Partners.

[Differences between Salesforce provided WSDL files](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004760&language=en_US&type=1)

Comment: what is stringly and loosely typed?

Comment: @UjwalaMane Strongly types means any change in architecture we need to generate new files while in partner it is generic and don't depend on org architecture.

Comment: okay.. in what scenario enterprise wsdl is used..?

Comment: @UjwalaMane They are primarily for customers. Because in that case, you won't change metadata daily.

Comment: ok.. thanks for reply.. its not related to my original question but i studied REST and currently doing SOAP.. i have doubt when to use SOAP and when to REST?

Comment: @UjwalaMane I suggest you post a new question with that and you can close this question by accepting this answer if it helps you.